# Clarification of WatchKit Performance tip regarding scene simplification

Tags: watchkit

Can anyone clarify this statement from the [WatchKit Development Tips](https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/) page?

> **Simplify controller scenes.**
>   Reduce the number of hidden objects as much as possible to significantly improve load time. For example, five versions of a controller’s layout in a single controller scene will result in all objects being created before the controller is displayed

I've read it a few dozen times now and can't figure out what it's trying to say.

1. What is a "scene"?  Is it referring to the Storyboard scene?
2. Are "hidden objects" referring to literally hidden UI elements like a hidden button?
3. How is it possible to have five versions of a controller's layout?  This just does not compute.

When a storyboard is loaded, and there are, say, 10 different WKInterfaceControllers in the file, will that be very slow even if the initial controller is blank?  Aren't these only loaded as-needed?  **Or, would it be better to have a single table with 10 prototype rows - each of which is actually a stand-alone interface - which are only instantiated one at a time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we can't programmatically add interface elements to controllers in the current version of WatchKit, any interface elements that we might need to display must be included in a Storyboard scene. By including these initially-hidden elements, we can programmatically hide or unhide these elements as needed.

For example, it's common to include a full-screen label that is initially hidden. Then, if a full-screen message needs to be shown for some reason, the text is populated, the label is unhidden, and the rest of the elements on the screen are hidden. To make hiding a set of elements easier, they're typically included in a `WKInterfaceGroup`, so that only the top-level group element needs to be hidden.

So, to answer your questions:

1. Indeed, a "scene" is a standard Storyboard scene.
2. Yes, "hidden objects" is referring to literally hidden objects as I've described above.
3. Using the method I've described, you could create five top-level `WKInterfaceGroup` elements, each with its own set of controls and layout. Then, you'd likely unhide the one that makes sense to display and hide all the others.

I use these techniques in my own app, though I typically don't have more than three top-level groups.

So yes, because it takes time to initialize and layout all of these elements (even if they're hidden), the recommendation is to keep it to a minimum.

Regarding the loading of interface controllers in a storyboard, you're correct that only the interface controllers that are needed are loaded. However, if you have a set of five page-based controllers, they'll all be loaded and initialized before the first page is activated. Other controllers would then be loaded as appropriate.

Creating unique rows is another possibility, but whether you do that or simply hide/unhide top-level groups depends on your app's specific needs. As always, it's worth testing on actual hardware.

Comment: It seems like using the table-based approach may indeed be preferable to the hidden-groups approach, depending on a) actual performance, and b) UI animation/appearance differences between inserting/removing rows and hiding/unhiding groups.  Without a definitive answer on this point, the generic Apple-provided advice of having simpler scenes is somewhat obvious: of course a smaller-footprint UI loads faster.  Your clarification is definitely a welcome sanity check, though, and a helpful, thoroughly-clear description of one approach to dynamic UI.  Thanks!